# In the same TimelineMax timeline, how to specify `repeat` in a tween?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a question about **GSAP**'s `TimelineMax`. I have a one timeline and some animations.

How to specify repeat on a tween inside a `TimelineMax` instance while still be able to continue with the remaining animations.

Below is my code. If I animate `$inputicon`, it will loop infinitely and the rest of the animations don't continue.

```
var sloganAnimation = new TimelineMax();
sloganAnimation.addLabel('textEffect')
    .staggerFromTo($slogan.find('span'), 0.01,
        { display: 'none' },
        { display: 'inline-block' }, 0.03, 'textEffect')
    .staggerFromTo($inputicon, 0.8,
        { autoAlpha: 0, repeat: -1 },
        { autoAlpha: 1, repeat: -1 }, 0.8, 'textEffect')
    .fromTo($('.quote-side'), .3, { height: 0 }, { height: 145 })
    .from('.blocker', .8, { autoAlpha: 0, y: -20, ease: Power3.easeOut });
```

Comment: `TimelineMax` can hold multiple `TimelineMax` objects within it. What you are asking, if I have been able to understand it correctly, is to be able to repeat a certain part of your main `sloganAnimation` timeline based on a certain condition to a certain number of times. I would suggest to put that part (i.e. `$inputicon` part) into its own timeline, add it into main timeline and based on your condition, either play the main timeline with no repeats or `.pause()` the main timeline and `.play()` the internal timeline with `repeat`.

Comment: Also, if you intend to repeat infinitely, how is the rest of the animation going to play? Can you put together a simple fiddle demonstrating this scenario please along with the conditions that make the timeline either repeat infinitely or doesn't repeat and just carries on.

Comment: by the way, you can try giving the tweens for `.quote-side` & `.blocker` elements, an exact `position` in the timeline. even if the positions are actually the sum of durations of previous tweens, but you can calculate on your own and pass them that. this way, there will be no-relation-with/no-dependency-on the previous tween's completion event (which basically doesn't really fire thanks to `repeat: -1`).

Comment: @Tahir Ahmed,  Thanks your suggestion ! It worked for me and i thank add more than one timeline to handle tween animate is the more efficient way.

Comment: glad you figured it out. have fun :)